# Library for searching texts

Tags: open-source, library, text-search

For a project that searches textual files (mostly unstructured), I would like to use a library that can accomplish the following criteria:

- Fast search of thousands to hundreds of thousands keywords, returning their start and end position
- Limited search for regular expressions (potentially thousands in parallel) (It's hard to describe limited here, I'm mostly using repetitions, wildcards, optional characters)
- Support for searching words

The search results are then processed again:

- Arbitrary logical operations (AND, OR, NOT, combinations)
- Distance checks (e.g. the two keywords are ANDed, but need to occur mostly N characters apart)

Optional, but would be really great:

- Phonetic search
- Resillience to typos

Also, I want to be able to associate certain actions with search hits.

C++ or Java would work for me. Open-source is a must.

Comment: https://www.powergrep.com/m/library.html?wlr=1 maybe

Answer (score 0):

The python [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) & [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) libraries are very powerful for this sort of thing and can be combined with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to parallelise the work.

Can I also suggest taking a look at Pythons Natural Language Toolkit [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/).

Not C++/Jave but definitely Open Source.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise: The documents themselves don't need to be processed in parallel, but the keyword search needs to be (eg. using Aho-Corasick instead of Knuth-Morris-Pratt).